# Venue History Pagination

Tags: api, pagination, foursquare

How are we supposed to paginate through the `venuehistory` (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/venuehistory) endpoint? In the docs, it mentions two parameters, `beforeTimestamp` and `afterTimestamp`, but the result set contains no reference timestamp points to paginate from. Am I missing something?

***Background***

I'm testing currently testing on an account with 22 items, so perhaps the pagination hasn't kicked in yet, but it would still be nice to cover this scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

/users/venuehistory returns the user's whole venuehistory, so typically you do not need to paginate it. The beforeTimestamp and afterTimestamp are used if you want to only show history from a certain time period (such as only showing check-ins in January, for a calendar view of check-ins).